# Getting path of an image which was set to a label

Tags: java

After I set an image to an label from path

```
    String img3D = "/images/3D.jpg";
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(img3D));
    lblImage = new JLabel(icon);
    lblImage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setContentPane(lblImage);
```

Keep in mind that the image can change (using a random for example). I want to get the path of the image of the label and save it.

I know how to save but I dont know how to get the path of an item, is there something like `lblImage.getIcon().getPath` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default. There is a huge amount of ways to get an image without reading a file really, so it would not make much sense to store a useless string (I can't see a use for it).

**HOWEVER**

- You can make your own `ImageIconExt` class with the info and check using instanceof.

**OR**

- Use reflection to get the private `location` or `filename` fields in ImageIcon. Note - this is hacky and the fields are transient.